# Requires substitute arguments to perform a pearl script using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Requires substitute arguments to perform a Perl script using bash.
I have a script that runs on the gem like this:

```
./script.pl "URL"
```

I needed to substitute "URL" substitute the value of a file using bash.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
./script.pl "$( cat file )"
```

or

```
./script.pl "$(< file )"
```

or

```
<file xargs ./script.pl
```

or

```
xargs -a file ./script.pl
```